# Simulator to test IVR application

Tags: ivr

I am developing IVR system using asterisk . To test my application , I need PRI lines and PRI card whose cose is around 30000 k . Is there any simulator available for same which i can use for my application.

Answer (score 1):

For most testing of IVR applications, a softphone over SIP is sufficient. If TDM is truly required, one option is [TDMoE](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+TDMoE) (TDM over Enternet) which is functionally similiar as a PRI; however, it can be run on standard Ethernet.

Comment: U mean to say VOIP phone is sufficent to test IVR. Currently I have broadband land line connection which is provided by AIRTEL. Can i use this for testing ? if yes any idea how

Comment: If your VoIP phone supports SIP you could definite a SIP endpoint in your Asterisk configuration (sip.conf) and configure a line connect to it. A simpler way of testing might be to use a SIP softphone like [Blink](http://www.icanblink.com/).